# Vaadin 7 url navigation hashbang

Tags: java, url, navigation, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to fully understand Navigation in Vaadin 7. I read [the Navigator Chapter](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/advanced.navigator.html) in the Vaadin book but still have some practical questions.

Basically it is about using the bang (!). When do I need to set it and why?

- There is a view (myview)
- There is a parameter (param=X)
- The parameter is identifying a displayed label

Example for browser history:
I need to set the bang (!) or clicking back in the browser does not work, because the parameters is not passed the the views enter function:

```
private void showInfo(String info) {
    infoLabel.setValue(info);
    Page.getCurrent().setUriFragment("!" + "myview/param=" + info, false);
}
```

Example for navigation after button click:
I must not set the bang (!) or else the url fragment changes to "#!myview//param=X" (contains double /)

```
@Override
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
    getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("myview/param=X")
}
```

Am I mixing two concepts here or is there a utility that does that for me and I'm not knowing it? Or do I just have to know about these 2 cases and decide about the bang myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to set the '!' at all - except you want force your sites to be crawled by search engines (see [GoogleDevelopers Spec](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification?hl=de&csw=1)). Some people even say, these hash bangs are [very bad UI practice](http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs).

Or is it a requirement for your application that its whole content is indexed by search engines ?

Comment: I don't care about indexed by search engines at all, but as I wrote, the back (history) function from the browser does not work in vaadin if it is not set. The `Navigator` from vaadin ignores the parameters.