# reloading page with parameter in url fragment adds extra slash character in vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin7

I am calling

```
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("myview/param=myparam");
```

and the Navigator opens the View registered as "myview" where the parameters
can be obtained from the ViewChangeEvent by calling

```
event.getParameters()
```

which returns "param=myparam". My browser displays the url

```
myapp/#!myview/param=myparam
```

However, if I reload the page (e.g. using F5)

```
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo("!myview/param=myparam");
```

(note the extra exclamation mark) will be called and the url changes to

```
myapp/#!myview//param=myparam
```

(note the double slash which is not supposed to be a comment), which obviously is a problem and actually every
page reload adds another slash. Am I doing something wrong here or how else can this be resolved ? I am using CDIViewProvider which might be of interest.

Note: It looks like someone had a similar problem here
[Vaadin 7 url navigation hashbang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566885/vaadin-7-url-navigation-hashbang)
but this does not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not realize that when pressing F5 the UI is reloaded. There was a call like

```
String uriFragment = getPage().getUriFragment();
getUI().getNavigator().navigateTo(uriFragment);
```

in the initialization code of my UI class. Apparently the exclamation mark is included in the return of  getUriFragment(), i.e. it returns "!myview/param=myparam". I fixed this by simply stripping the exclamation mark at this point.